# Is it acceptable to perform inference on unlabeled data utilized during SSL training

Tags: semi-supervised-learning, methodology

I am facing a classification problem and I have both labeled and unlabeled data. To make use of the unlabeled data, I have chosen to adopt the [self-learning approach](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/semi_supervised.html), which is a type of semi-supervised learning. My ultimate goal is to predict the class labels of the unlabeled data.

So, I'm wondering whether I can still use the same set of unlabeled data that I used during training for making predictions during the inference stage.

Comment: That sounds a bit like transductive learning (except that doesn't create a model that can be deployed more generally)?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transduction_(machine_learning)